# C++ - Complex Value Calculation Error in Cross Spectral Density

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, frequency-analysis

I am a very beginner in c++ and I want to do some spectral calculations, in this case calculating the 'Cross Spectral Density' of two signal (`vecFirst, vecSecond`), which are already processed with a FastFourierTransformation. Resulting in `freqvec` and `freqvec2`, containing complex values for each frequency.

For this calculating it is essential to keep every value as a complex value. E.g.: CoSpectrum, which is calculated in **line 6**, should has a complex value as a result.

```
RowVectorXcd freqvec;
RowVectorXcd freqvec2;
fft.fwd(freqvec, vecFirst);
fft.fwd(freqvec2, vecSecond);

// # Create conjugate complex
freqvec.conjugate();
freqvec2.conjugate();
RowVectorXcd Rxy(freqvec.cols());
for (int i = 0; i < freqvec.cols(); i++) {
        std::complex<double>CoSpectrum( freqvec(i).real() * freqvec2(i).real() + freqvec(i).imag() * freqvec2(i).imag()) ;
        std::complex<double>QuadSpectrum( freqvec(i).real() * freqvec2(i).imag() - freqvec(i).real() * freqvec2(i).imag() ) ;
        std::complex<double>CoSpectrum_sqr = CoSpectrum * CoSpectrum ;
        std::complex<double>QuadSpectrum_sqr = QuadSpectrum * QuadSpectrum ;
        Rxy(i) = sqrt(std::complex<double>(CoSpectrum_sqr + QuadSpectrum_sqr)) ;
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately I only get complex values with zero in the imaginary part.**

Can anyone tell me why? 
I am guessing the expression `freqvec(i).real()` only returns a double value, but how can I get the real part but keep it a complexvalue. Or, accordingly, just multiply the imaginary part of a complex number with the real part of another and keep it the result a complex double.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You're passing a single value for the std::complex constructor. It needs two doubles for real and imaginary part or a complex value.Calling real() or imag() returns only real numbers - real + j imag.

Comment: `std::complex<double>(freqvec(i).real(), 0)` - complex number containing only the real part and `std::complex<double>(0, freqvec(i).imag())` - with only the imaginary part

Comment: i think you don't need to conjugate of both ffts, you can directly multiply std::complex values and `std::complex::abs()` for the magnitude.

Comment: At first: Thank you very much. I had thought of something like that, but wasn't sure. Thank got there a nice people like you who care about beginners.

So I changed the snippet as following:

Comment: I cannot try it but AFAIK the CSD is Fourier of th cross-correlatopn or product of fft of the first and rhe conj of the second so ˋauto csd = freqvec(i) * frecvec2(i).conj;ˋ and yo can call ˋcsd.abs()ˋ to get the magnitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: Thank you very much. I had thought of something like that, but wasn't sure. Thank got there a nice people like you who care about beginners.

So I changed the snippet as following:

```
    // ### Attempting to compute the Frequency Power for Frequency Bins..
    RowVectorXcd freqvec;
    RowVectorXcd freqvec2;
    fft.fwd(freqvec, vecFirst);
    fft.fwd(freqvec2, vecSecond);
    std::cout<<"freqvec:"<<freqvec.cols()<<std::endl;

    // ### Attempting to compute the PowerSpectralDensitiy(PSD) and CrossSpectralDensity(CSD). The cross-spectral density is the Fourier transform of the cross-correlation function.
    RowVectorXcd Rxy(n_Epochs, freqvec.cols());
    RowVectorXcd Rxx(n_Epochs, freqvec.cols());
    RowVectorXcd Ryy(n_Epochs, freqvec.cols());
    for (int i = 0; i < n_Epochs; i++) {
            std::complex<double>CoSpectrum( std::complex<double>(freqvec(i).real(),0) * std::complex<double>(freqvec2(i).real(),0) + std::complex<double>(0,freqvec(i).imag()) * std::complex<double>(0, freqvec2(i).imag()) ) ;
            std::complex<double>QuadSpectrum( std::complex<double>(freqvec(i).real(), 0) * std::complex<double>(0, freqvec2(i).imag()) - std::complex<double>(0,freqvec(i).imag()) * std::complex<double>(freqvec2(i).real(), 0) ) ;
            std::complex<double>CoSpectrum_sqr = CoSpectrum * CoSpectrum ;
            std::complex<double>QuadSpectrum_sqr = QuadSpectrum * QuadSpectrum ;
            Rxy(i) = sqrt(std::complex<double>(CoSpectrum_sqr + QuadSpectrum_sqr)) ;
            Rxx(i) = std::complex<double>(freqvec(i).real(), 0) * std::complex<double>(freqvec(i).real(), 0) + std::complex<double>(0, freqvec(i).imag()) * std::complex<double>(0, freqvec(i).imag()) ;
            Ryy(i) = std::complex<double>(freqvec2(i).real(), 0) * std::complex<double>(freqvec2(i).real(), 0) + std::complex<double>(0, freqvec2(i).imag()) * std::complex<double>(0, freqvec2(i).imag()) ;
        }
    }
```

This solved my problem. Thanks again for the nice discussion.